# Angularjs - multiple directives nested on the same page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just started working with AngularJs and am having some problems in the management of multiple directives.

The two directives have to perform the following tasks:

1) Create an animation when the page is loaded with animated

2) Create a background parallax on some div

Through some resources found on the net I could get aa two directives that individually work well, but if I try to make them work together with the outer one prevents the internal directives to do their jobs.

This is the code(html):

```
<div ng-view ng-controller="MyCtrl" anim-class>
    <section parallax-background parallax-ratio="0.5" style="background: url(img/parallax1.jpg);">
        //some code
    </section>
</div>
```

This is the code(js):

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [
"ngRoute",
"ngAnimate",
]);



app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider.
    when("/first-page", {
      templateUrl: "first-page.html",
      animate: "slideTop"
    }).
    when("/second-page", {
      templateUrl: "second-page.html",
      animate: "slideTop"
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/first-page"
    });

});

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

});

// PAGE ANIMATE DIRECTIVE
app.directive('animClass',function($route){
  return {
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
      var enterClass = $route.current.animate;
      elm.addClass(enterClass)
      scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
        elm.removeClass(enterClass)
        elm.addClass($route.current.animate)
      })
     }
  }
});

// PARALLAX DIRECTIVE
app.directive('parallaxBackground', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    scope: {
      parallaxRatio: '@',
    },
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
      var setPosition = function () {
        var calcValY = (elem.prop('offsetTop') - $window.pageYOffset) * ($scope.parallaxRatio ? $scope.parallaxRatio : 1.1 );
        // horizontal positioning
        elem.css('background-position', "50% " + calcValY + "px");
       };

      // set our initial position - fixes webkit background render bug
      angular.element($window).bind('load', function(e) {
        setPosition();
        $scope.$apply();
      });

      angular.element($window).bind("scroll", setPosition);
      angular.element($window).bind("touchmove", setPosition);
    }  // link function
  };
}]);
```

How can I make sure that the two ( or more ) directives are working properly .
Thank You.

Comment: it's not really clear what you are asking here; there is no issue declaring nested directives; if these two directives are interfering with each other, a more complete example that demonstrates the behavior would be helpful.

Comment: I'm still not clear exactly what your problem is, but have you tried this in different browsers?  IE11 and Safari on Windows don't animate the page load (slide up) but Chrome, Firefox and Opera do.  If you can strip out all unnecessary elements from the example page to narrow the problem down you might find people will be more able to help.  Putting it into something like CodePen or JSFiddle would be encouraging too.

Comment: This is the file Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/j7r3s33Y3GcTyH2Fop9K?p=preview

In the index.html file at "ng-view" associate Directive custom "anim-class" which has the task of animating the entry page.

Inside pages then I associate the Directive custom "parallax-background" with which I would like to turn the parallax only on certain section but not working.

If you delete the Directive "anim-class" from the container instead parallax works and do not understand what a conflict.